# Cannot capture frames other than broadcast or multicast in Wireshark

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, wireshark, sniffing

My problem is that I cannot capture any frames other than broadcast or multicast over Wireshark on my WLAN interface (eg. no ICMP packets, no HTTP packets, etc.)

Please follow details below:

- OS: Linux KALI 2016.1 Rolling Release 64bit (u#1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5kali4)
- NIC: Linksys WUSB600Nv2 Dual-Band (RaLink RT3572 - Driver: rt2800usb - mac80211: capable - Assigned as WLAN0)
- WLAN0 put to monitor mode (using airmon-ng start wlan0) therefore listening on **wlan0mon** Channel 01 on Wireshark
- Test AP: Linksys E3000 on Channel 01 - Open security no encryption
- Second Client: Win7 Laptop pinging the AP (ICMPv4) & Surfing web
- Wireshark version 2.0.3

However I cannot capture any UNICAST frames. Please tell me what I am missing,

Answer (score 1):

So that everyone knows the problem was with the Kernel, there's a new issue with kernels below v4.4.0 with RT chipset (on KALI).

Upgrading the kernel solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the filters `not broadcast and not multicast` so that only unicast traffic remains. That should make thinks a lot more clear.

If unicast traffic does not show, you may have an anti-virus interfering with the traffic capture.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply,

1. I applied the filter the outcome was no packets at all.
2. No antivirus or firewall is running unless there's one built-in on KALI that I am not aware of.

any thoughts?

Comment: Do you see any ARP requests in Wireshark?

Comment: Yes I can see ARP request

Comment: Double check if somehow UFW is installed. Command: ufw disable - it will disable if it's installed and active.

Comment: Checked it, not installed ("command not found")

Comment: Put your card into monitor mode and capture on mon0 to see all packets instead of just broadcast/MC. To test the differences after doing this, netstat -a can help, along with the wireshark output. If you can, post a screenshot of WS captures.

Comment: As mentioned, I have already done putting WLAN card into monitor mode and Wireshark is listening on the monitoring interface.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you capture on the "mon0" interface, not on the "wlan0" interface ? Also, make sure to check this out: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN ; it gives details about setups.